# YouTube JS code - 100% width, muted and locked

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have the JS code and must convert this to `100% width`, `800px height` and `pointer-events: none;` is there any chance to add this to this code ?
This code change youtube video to muted.

```
<!-- 1. The <div> tag will contain the <iframe> (and video player) -->  
<div id="player"></div>
<script>      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'loop': 1,'playlist': '2oqCAmfc0D0','autohide':1,'showinfo': 0,'disablekb': 1,'rel': 0,'wmode':'opaque' },
          videoId: '2oqCAmfc0D0',
width: '100%',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this you mean? [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/59o7sh11/)

```
<!-- 1. The <div> tag will contain the <iframe> (and video player) -->  
<div id="player" style="pointer-events: none;"></div>
<script>      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'loop': 1,'playlist': '2oqCAmfc0D0','autohide':1,'showinfo': 0,'disablekb': 1,'rel': 0,'wmode':'opaque' },
          videoId: '2oqCAmfc0D0',
width: '100%',
height: '800px',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
      }
</script>
```

Be warned, pointer-events has some compatibility issues with older IE. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Another way of doing the same thing is to have an overlaying div with visibility: hidden. Or an overlaying transparent div.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. Is there any chance to have full filled youtube video 100% and 800px without black rectangles ?

Comment: Then [this](http://jsfiddle.net/59o7sh11/1/) might work, but it's not a very clean solution. There's no real way from what I saw to get the background color out, just to scale the video according to the aspect ratio. vw units = viewport width. The size of the height is given by the 16:9 aspect ratio of your video.

Comment: Is there any chance to leave the static height of frame and 100% width on every screen resolution ?

Comment: If you put static height on the iframe, then it will automatically be filled with black background.
Maybe you can achieve the same thing by using a container.
Top aligned: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/59o7sh11/2/)
Middle aligned: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/59o7sh11/3/)

Comment: Thats ok but I mean something like this. Full filled height on every resolution. Some part of videos can be hidden. Check https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b4gt4k5zu6mpio4/askq.jpg